# Find who owns a doi:// domain? (A "whois" for doi Links)

Tags: doi

Is there a command-line tool, or a website, or a "directory service",  that I can use to determine which organization (or person) owns a `doi//` domain?

I want to know "Who owns `10.2312`?"

(That's the same as: who owns `doi://10.2312?`).

(I could also ask on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, or academia.SE, but this "open data" forum is bigger and seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Crossref DOI Resolution https://dx.doi.org/
10.2312 used by DataCite (10.SERV/DATACITE)